# richfaces reRender executed before action listener completion

Tags: java, richfaces, jsf-1.2, rerender

I have a Richfaces listShuttle component that I need to have the source values (left side) sorted. For this purpose, after the value of the component has changed, I have a backing bean method to sort the elements, and the I want to rerender the listShuttle.

the xhtml code:

```
<a4j:region>
    <rich:listShuttle id="#{id}_listShuttle"
        sourceValue="#{bean.displayedItems}"
        targetValue="#{bean.selectedItems}" var="item"
        fastOrderControlsVisible="false" orderControlsVisible="false"
        fastMoveControlsVisible="false"
        style="margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:15px;">

        <f:converter converterId="#{converterId}" />
        <a4j:support event="onlistchanged" action="#{bean.sortList}"
            reRender="#{updateId}, #{id}_listShuttle" />

        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
        </rich:column>
    </rich:listShuttle>
</a4j:region>
```

It is a component I use in more places, so I pass some parameters to it.

The problem is that the action `action="#{bean.sortList}"`  is executed after the rerender phase. I want this action to be executed before the rerender phase.

The order of the actions is this:
- getDisplayedItems
- setDisplayedItems
- sortList

Any idea how to make the listShuttle rerender after the sortList action?

Comment: How did you end up sorting this out, Alina?

Answer (score 0):

Would adding immediate=true to your sortList do the trick ?